# Ignore inner join if there are no records?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

These two requirements must be met:

- Select products that have the status "waiting".
- The last e-mail must have been sent 3 days ago.

The following tables and columns are given:

products: id, name, status_id, notification

status: id, name

emaillogs: id, product_id, subject, text, date_created

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    product.id
FROM
    product
        LEFT JOIN
    status ON product.status_id = status.id
        INNER JOIN
    emaillog ON product.id = emaillog.product_id
        AND (emaillog.date_created <= '2018-11-04 16:32:49')
WHERE
    (status.name = 'waiting' AND product.notification = 1)
GROUP BY emaillog.product_id
```

This works only if there are records in the emaillogs table. If there are no records in the emaillogs table, the products should nevertheless be selected.

Comment: You just need to make the second `JOIN` a `LEFT JOIN` as well. Note also that you have `status_id.term_key` in your `WHERE` clause but no table called `status_id` in the query

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` rather than ordinary inner `JOIN` if you want to preserve unjoined rows in your result set.  But, beware, mentioning a column from a left-joined table in your WHERE clause converts the left join to an inner join.